# Реализация имеющегося алгоритма на С++

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, динамические-массивы

Всем добрый день!
Вопрос не из легких, но вдруг кто-то из присутствующих здесь когда-либо сталкивался с этой задачей.
Необходимо реализовать следующий алгоритм на С++, уже долго над этим сижу, никак не могу придумать, как правильно это сделать. Есть такая таблица с решением задачи (прикрепила картинку).
Имеется матрица с тремя столбцами (A,B,Sij). A и В - города. Sij - показатель, который нужно рассчитывать для данного алгоритма. Первая пара А и В заносится в вектор, в данном случае маршрут 1 (столбик "маршрут", где 0 - точка, откуда выезжает машина, и куда возвращается). Есть предел в 500 км для маршрута. Для каждой следующей строчки маршрута мы проверяем два условия:

1 - оба пункта А и В вместе не задействованы в каком-либо из ранее построенных маршрутов

2 - один из пунктов является первой или последней точкой в каком-либо из ранее построенных маршрутов (например, для строки 2, пункт B (10) был первым в маршруте из предыдущей строки)

Если оба условия выполнены, ставим + в 4 и 5 столбцах и добавляем этот отрезок пути в маршрут (например, было 0-10-11-0, а после добавления отрезка 1-10 стало 0-1-10-11-0)
Далее считаем общее расстояние маршрута (по матрице расстояний, которая дана), и если оно меньше 500 км, принимаем этот маршрут как новый.

Аналогично все для всех следующих строчек. Если в какой-либо строчке оба пункта еще нигде не использовались, создаем еще один маршрут, называем его 2 и последующие строчки проверяем уже как для 1 маршрута, так и для второго.

Алгоритм продолжается, пока не будут задействованы все пункты.

Я не прошу полного решения данной задачи, я надеюсь, что мне хотя бы помогут с идеей, как логично собрать в кучу столько проверок для каждой строки. Потому что я в них уже запуталась
(этот алгоритм - реализация метода Кларка-Райта для решения задачи маршрутизации транспорта).
Заранее спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы не описываете вариант, когда условие 1 выполняется, а условие 2 нет - т.е. один из пунктов упомянут в некоем маршруте, но не как конечный. Судя по приведённой таблице, в этом случае ставятся сплошные минусы (кроме колонки `1`), и обрабатывается следующая строка? *как логично собрать в кучу столько проверок для каждой строки.* так их всего-то три штуки, проверок...

Comment: Если хоть одно из условий не выполняется, нужно перейти к следующей строке. Их всего-то три штуки, но я задаю вопрос, потому что не могу придумать, как их реализовать.

Comment: Их хоть и три, но все условия нужно проверять для каждого маршрута. Т.е. когда уже, например, три маршрута частично записано, каждую новую строку нужно сверять с каждым из маршрутов. Это значительно все усложняет

Comment: А что тут реализовывать? Номер текущей строки - есть. Берёте обе точки, и пробегаетесь по предыдущим строчкам на предмет выполнения пунктов 1 и 2. Если выполняются, считаете цену нового маршрута и проверяете выход за границу. Всё ж просто и плоско, как блин... *Т.е. когда уже, например, три маршрута частично записано* Что значит "частично"? для любой строки запись - окончательная, если строка заполнена, в дальнейшем она уже не изменится. *каждую новую строку нужно сверять с каждым из маршрутов.* И что? ну квадратичная сложность, а куда деваться?

Comment: Частично-значит, что маршрут еще не конечный.  Я понимаю логику решения, я прошу помощи с написанием кода. Спасибо

Comment: *Частично-значит, что маршрут еще не конечный.* А это неважно. На текущий момент он - конечный. Другое дело, что в будущем он может быть нарощен - но на эту строку таблицы сей факт никак не влияет. Так что на момент обработки строки маршрут в ней - окончательный.